# Set Accessibility Identifier on ActionSheet in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode-ui-testing, xcuitest

How can i set the accessibility identifier for an ActionSheet in SwiftUI.

I want to tap a button of it, because i need to identify it for my `XCUITest`.

I'm currently trying this for my :

```swift
app.sheets[""].buttons["Choose Photo"].tap()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by using this:

```
app.sheets.firstMatch.buttons["Choose Photo"].tap()
```